# calculate measure for some members that create some percent of total measure

Tags: mdx, measure

We have a cube that it has one measure (Commission Amount) and two dimensions customer and Date.
I want calculate ratio of (count of customers who create 80 percent of Commission Amount) to (count of total customer)
It is important to say that customers are sorted base on their Commission Amount
How can solve this problem? And what must use to solve this query?

Comment: what environment are you in when writing the mdx ? ssrs, modrian ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the **TopPercent()** function here:

```
TopPercent(
    existing [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].Members, 
    80,  
    [Measures].[Commission Amount]  
)
/
existing [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].Members.Count
```

Comment: existing is powerful but not implemented in all environments - I don't believe it is within Mondrian

Comment: Yeah, you can remove the existing keyword. It shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same approach as Danylo - I just added an extra `COUNT` and deleted some, possibly redundant, `EXISTING` keywords:

```
DIVIDE(
  COUNT(
    TOPPERCENT(
      {[Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS}, 
      80,  
      [Measures].[Commission Amount]  
    )
  )
  ,[Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS.COUNT
)
```