# DAX % of total count if measure qualifies criteria

Tags: powerpivot, dax

DAX 2013 standalone power pivot.

I have a sales table with Product and Brand columns, and Sales measure which explicitly sums up sales column.

**Task in hand:** I need to create 1 measure  **RANK** which would ...

- if Product is filtered expressly, then return count of Products that have higher or equal sales amount, divided by total count of products.
- If it's a subtotal brand level, show the same but for brands.

**My current approach** is using RANK and then MAXX of rank which seems working but a no-go - slow nightmare. Excel runs out of memory.

**Research:** it's been a week. This is the most relevant post i found anywhere,  [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304288/calculate-measure-for-some-members-that-create-some-percent-of-total-measure) , but it's in MDX.

In my example picture, I'm showing Excel formulas with which I can get to the result. Ideally there shouldn't be any helpers, 1 formula for all.

I.E.

```
RANK:=IF( HASONEFILTER(PRODUCTS[PRODUCT], HELPER_PROD, HELPER_BRAND)
```

where HELPER_PROD part would be something like this - need to find a way to refer to "current" result in pivot table like Excel does using [@[...:

```
HELPER_PROD:=COUNTX(ALL(PRODUCTS), [SALES]>=[@[SALES]]) / COUNTX(ALL(PRODUCTS))
HELPER_BRAND:=COUNTX(
              DISTINCT(ALL(PRODUCTS[BRAND])), 
              [SALES]>=[@[SALES]]) / 
              COUNT(DISTINCT(ALL(PRODUCTS[BRAND]))
```

[image: FLOW]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Earlier" function to compare with the current record.

```
ProductsWithHigherSales:=CALCULATE(countrows(sales),
FILTER(all(Sales),
countrows(filter(Sales,Sales[Sales]<=EARLIER(Sales[Sales]))) 
))
```

Using Earlier function in measures: [can-earlier-be-used-in-dax-measures](https://javierguillen.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/can-earlier-be-used-in-dax-measures/)

Used workbook: [Excel File](http://wimv.be/pbi/SO43734070.xlsx)

Comment: Hey thanks, I appreciate help. Two issues though, 1) i was trying to avoid creating numerous helper tables -  my data model is not perfect but i've got to stick to it for the time being. 2) your solution works fine on product level, but doesn't work on brand totals though, it should be "ranking" brands, i.e. since i have only 3, values returned by this measure cannot be 14 etc - which is what i see in your pivot if i put brand before product. It's a good tip about EARLIER, i didn't think it's possible - will research this now. Thanks, once again